# How can you tell if a phone is connected to a wifi network or a cell network?

Tags: java, blackberry, wifi

I'm working on an app that should behave differently depending on whether a user is sending requests through wifi or their cell network.  How can I detect which network the phone is connected to?

[This answer](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/154902-how-programatically-detect-if-wi-fi-turned.html) on the BlackBerry Forums looks promising, but I am not sure if knowing if wifi is turned on is equivalent to knowing which network requests will be sent over.

(We are targeting versions 4.3+, if it matters.)

Comment: how are you creating your connections?  Since you are supporting pre 5.0, I assume you are doing something similar to http://www.versatilemonkey.com/HttpConnectionFactory.java.  In which case have a look at the method getLastTransport().  The basic jest is that it records the last connection used.

Comment: @eSniff: Yeah, that's approximately how we're creating our connections.  Thanks for the link!  So you can't tell what protocol the next connection will use, just the last one?  What if the user has turned off wifi, lost cell signal, etc. in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Import net.rim.device.api.system.WLANInfo. After that check as follows:

if (WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
  /* wlan connected */
}

If it is connected, requests will be sent via WiFi.

Comment: That tells you if there's potentially usable wifi connection.  However when you physically connect the connection string explicitly tells it to use wifi or not.